# Read filename from list file, compress it and move to destination using bashscript

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a list file and a source file present in one directory (/int/source/HR100). So the contents of Source directory looks like below.

`Customer_Account_20211202.csv`
`Customer_Account.lst`

The list file (Customer_Account.lst) contains the name of the source file i.e Customer_Account_20211202.csv. Now I want to zip the source file and move it to a destination directory (/int/source/HR100/Archive). I am able to achieve the movement using a one liner unix command as shown below but I couldn't able to zip and move the file. My preference is Gunzip(.gz) format. Please help.

Code I am using:

`xargs -a Customer_Account.lst mv -t int/source/HR100/Archive;`

The above one liner moves the file without compressing. I want a one liner which will read the file from list , will compress and then move.

Comment: Does the file `Customer_Account.lst` contain exactly one line (one filename) ?

Comment: Yes it contains only one filename.

Answer (score 0):

Why a one liner? How about something like... (not tested)

```sh
while IFS= read -r file || [ -n "$file" ]; do
  printf '%s\n' "Doing file '$file'"

  tar -czf "$file.tar.gz" "$file"
  mv -- -t 'int/source/HR100/Archive' "$file.tar.gz"
done < 'Customer_Account.lst'
```

The first line in the `while ... do ... done` loop reads the file line by line

- See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418060/read-a-line-oriented-file-which-may-not-end-with-a-newline) for questions about the `[ -n "$file" ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` and `sh` to execute multiple commands.

```
xargs -a Customer_Account.lst -i sh -c "gzip {};mv {}.gz -t int/source/HR100/Archive;"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Can you tell me is it possible to rename a file and move? If Customer_Account.lst contains "DEM_Customer_Account_14122021111209_RC101.csv". How I can move it to target as "DEM_Customer_Account_14122021111209.csv", where i just need to get rid of everything after _RC and append the .csv. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Customer_Account.lst contain exactly one line, this command should do the job:

```
f=$(< Customer_Account.lst); gzip "$f" && mv "$f".gz int/source/HR100/Archive/
```